# How do I find exact values for $\sin (11\pi / 12)$ and $\cos (11\pi /12)$ given cis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

How do I find exact values for $\sin (\frac{11\pi}{12})$ and $\cos(\frac{11\pi}{12})$ given $\operatorname{cis}(\frac{11 \pi}{12}) = \operatorname{cis}(\frac{2\pi}{3} + \frac{\pi}{4})$?

I know that
$\operatorname{cis}(\frac{11\pi}{12}) =  \cos(\frac{11\pi}{12}) + i\sin (\frac{11\pi}{12})$.

I have tried writing it in polar form but I don't have $|z|$, the hypotenuse or the other sides. It should be in the second quadrant?

However, I know it is $15$ degrees for theta. 180 - $11\pi/12$

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should try drawing it, if the equations don't make enough sense.

Comment: May be you should try the formula $\mathrm{cis}(\alpha+\beta)=\mathrm{cis}(\alpha)\mathrm{cis}(\beta)$?

Comment: $|\cos t + i\sin t|=1$ for any $t$. i.e. the "hypotenuse" is 1, and the legs are cosine and sine.

Comment: OK - I think I got the correct answer. I just used @JyrkiLahtonen 's formula and then expanded it out to the following: 

cis (a+b) = cis(a) * cis(b)

cis (a+b) = (cos a + isin a)(cos b+ isin b)

Answer (score 5):

What I do is to leverage on the special angles,

1. Special angles. (*You need to remember them by heart)
   $$ \sin (\pi/6) = \cos (\pi/3) = 1/2 $$
   $$ \sin (\pi/3) = \cos (\pi/6) = \sqrt{3}/2 $$
   $$ \sin (\pi/4) = \cos (\pi/4) = 1/\sqrt{2} $$

Hence,

$$
\begin{align}
\exp \Big( i\frac{11\pi}{12} \Big) & = \exp \Big( i\frac{2\pi}{3} + i\frac{\pi}{4} \Big) \\
& = \exp \Big( i\frac{\pi}{3} + i\frac{\pi}{3} + i\frac{\pi}{4} \Big) \\
& = \exp \Big( i\frac{\pi}{3} \Big)\exp \Big( i\frac{\pi}{3} \Big)\exp \Big( i\frac{\pi}{4} \Big) \\
& = \Big( \cos \frac{\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{3} \Big)^2\Big( \cos \frac{\pi}{4} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{4} \Big) \\
& = \Big( \frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \Big)^2 \Big( \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \Big) \\
& = ... \\
\end{align}
$$

I will leave you to substitute the values and do the necessary expansion.
After which, you can separate the complex exponential to its real and imaginary parts to get the exact values of $\sin \frac{11\pi}{12}$ and $\cos \frac{11\pi}{12}$.

Hope it helps.